# Bad memory exception while using OpenCV background subtraction

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I want to perform background subtraction using open cv library in my IOS application. I have downloaded latest library from open cv website and successfully integrated it in my project. Now i am have trouble with it is that "when i call method `BackgroundSubtractor->apply` i get bad memory exception".

My code is here.

```
cv::Mat fgMaskMOG2;
cv::BackgroundSubtractor *pMOG2=cv::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
int i=0;
while (i<4) {
    i++;
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMG_%d",i] ofType:@"JPG"];
    cv::Mat frame=[self cvMatFromUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMG_%d.JPG",i]]];
    pMOG2->apply(frame, fgMaskMOG2,1);
}
cv::Mat output;
pMOG2->getBackgroundImage(output);
```

So how i can fix it ?

Comment: Have you checked in debugger that images are loaded and you have `Mat` frame?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: @JohnTracid Yes images were loaded. With 2.4 version i am able to perform task but i am having issue with 3.0

Comment: @trojanfoe There is no stacktrace just a bad memory exception coming from open cv library.

Comment: And do you have an exception breakpoint enabled so you can trap it in the debugger?

Comment: @trojanfoe  yes it is enable.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT). This is the exception.